# How many user can IIS support?

Tags: iis-7

Can IIS support multiple users, I'm thinking about 1000? If it can, how can I do it with asp.net?

Comment: Only the Chuck Norris version of IIS can support that many users

Comment: No the Chuck Norris version of IIS can support -1 user too.

Answer (score 0):

You must be talking about the number of simultaneous web users?

IIS7 can support any number of users, depending only on the site complexity and the server performance (and maybe your web farm). You don't have to do anything in ASP.NET (apart from optimizing it... Hmm it's a quite vast subject.)

IIS6 supports limited users numbers on non server versions of windows (win XP)

Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes,it does. In summary, I must study web farm for support any number of users,Right?

Comment: You should think about the real number of users you want to support. I am quite sure that it's not "unlimited". Maybe using a cloud platform could suit you... But being able to serve content to more users is never free.

Answer (score 0):

The number of users isn't the question you should be asking, instead look at the performance.

If your web server performance is poor you would need to deploy multiple web servers. Then you might want to consider load balancing so that jobs are distributed evenly.

It would be something that would need constant monitoring. This also highlights one of the advantages of cloud computing is being able to scale up with multiple web servers when needed or less during non peak periods thus saving costs.